# What does pneumatic operated and electrically controlled means?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus-a320, air-conditioning

I was going through A 320 FCOM and didn't understand this term

Answer (score 5):

Pneumatic operated: actuation by using air pressure. By opening a valve, high pressure air enters a cylinder, causing a piston to be pushed out. Typically, actuators of this type have two valves connected to two separate chambers, allowing for movement both ways.

The valves need opening and closing, though. This is what the "electrically controlled" part means: a small electric (typically electromagnetic) actuator will open or close based on an electric control signal.